# Word for the historical weight of significance of practical objects/buildings?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Is there a word for the feeling you get when looking at old machinery/practical objects/old industrial buildings when you feel the weight of their use by, and significance to, people of the past? I’m not talking about nostalgia, or wistfulness/longing for the past, but a sense of the value in to people, through utility, embuing the objects or buildings with some sort of totemic value, retrospectively. I feel this sensation very powerfully looking at ruined industrial buildings or in museums of old tools/machines.

Comment: Hi Hacopops, welcome to English Language & Usage. As you're looking for "a word", I've added the SWR tag. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. **You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used**."  [My emphasis]. You can add these details by clicking on the [edit] link. Also, if you think you might use our site again (and I hope you do!), please make sure you take the [Tour].  :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "totemic value"? (And wouldn't such a word apply to things of any time, not just the past?)

Answer (score 1):

**veneration**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/veneration)

n.

> 1. A feeling of profound respect or reverence: an object held in veneration.

As in:

> Being in the bedroom of a well preserved antebellum home, I felt a
>   profound sense of **veneration**, as if the original owners could walk
>   in any minute.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a kind of awe:

> **Awe** is the feeling of **respect and amazement** that you have when you are **faced with something wonderful** and *often* rather frightening.
>   (the [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/awe))

Of course, those great objects, industrial buildings and old machinery we are talking about are not frightening. But note that *often* doesn't mean *always*. The point is you feel respect and amazement. Here are some examples taken from various dictionaries:

1. She gazed in awe at the great stones.
2. His fellow officers regarded him with awe as some sort of genius.
3. She filled me with a sense of awe.
4. I've always held musicians in awe.
5. The scenery was absolutely stunning - I remember gazing in a state of awe over the landscape.